# Rails 6 actioncable app deploy to heroku failed application error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-6

i have created a rails app and using actioncable but while i push it heroku it gives me H10 application errror.

my logs

```
`block in ensure_listener_running'
2022-01-17T11:54:48.467823+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-01-17T11:54:48.344709+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/cable" host=rumichatapp.herokuapp.com request_id=f91c8ddd-605a-4db6-b9fb-db4efd2aeb44 fwd="157.40.141.184" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=441ms status=101 bytes=174 protocol=https
2022-01-17T11:54:48.660590+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-01-17T11:54:57.899598+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/cable" host=rumichatapp.herokuapp.com request_id=9a98e57d-ae1c-46c2-9e11-9bbe19e6a1e3 fwd="157.40.141.184" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-17T11:55:01.094359+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/cable" host=rumichatapp.herokuapp.com request_id=2c98011d-7e30-4a7a-bb03-2edd4b75c1d2 fwd="157.40.141.184" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-17T11:55:06.468878+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/cable" host=rumichatapp.herokuapp.com request_id=bc2c369e-e74b-407c-ad0a-06f5a6509907 fwd="157.40.141.184" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-17T11:55:11.172160+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/users" host=rumichatapp.herokuapp.com request_id=425add70-3ff1-43b5-aecd-2167dfe1a8ba fwd="157.40.141.184" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-17T11:55:11.972897+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/users" host=rumichatapp.herokuapp.com request_id=8bcb3d19-6247-4689-932b-6b201f41b12d fwd="157.40.141.184" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-17T11:55:14.014700+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/cable" host=rumichatapp.herokuapp.com request_id=904c5ce0-917c-4ac5-89f9-f3f33559e5b9 fwd="157.40.141.184" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-17T11:55:14.414472+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/users" host=rumichatapp.herokuapp.com request_id=58631226-c0f0-4a2c-bd64-4fd814f88cf4 fwd="157.40.141.184" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-17T11:55:17.291697+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rumichatapp.herokuapp.com request_id=a835ca62-798d-438a-be5c-249a3791e001 fwd="157.40.141.184" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

i added my wss urls into `enviroments/production.rb` file

```rb
 config.action_cable.url = 'wss://rumichatapp.herokuapp.com/cable'
  config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'https://rumichatapp.herokuapp.com/', /https:\/\/rumichatapp.herokuapp.*/ ]
```

and i also executed `heroku run rails db:migrate` command.

the production group gems of my `Gemfile`

```rb
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
end
```

what i am doing wrong ? please help !

Comment: There could be several reason -> do you have a redis plugin ? You can find some guidance here https://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/deploying-action-cable-to-heroku/

Answer (score 0):

For me it was not setting the aws credential. I forgot to do it when I created a new app that was cloned and modified from an already working project. I found this by opening the rails console and doing a heroku restart.